# Enumeration of uniform polyhedra

Tags: reference-request, polyhedra

[I already asked this question on MSE ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860619/enumeration-of-uniform-polyhedra)) but got no answer so I am trying here]

It is known that there are two infinite classes of polyhedra (prisms and antiprisms) together with $75$ uniform polyhedra that do not belong to these classes.

For regular convex polyhedra (i.e., Platonic solids), quasi- and semiregular convex polyhedra (i.e., Archimedean solids), and regular nonconvex polyhedra (i.e., Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra), there are proofs that no more than $5$ resp. $13$ resp $4$ can exist.

For the remaining $53$ uniform star polyhedra I only know of a proof that relies on a computer search. Is there any proof done without using computers that there are no more than $53$ uniform star polyhedra (e.g., in an analogous way as the proof for Archimedean solids)?